# Angular spinner is not appearing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using urish/angular-spinner but it is not working when I try to use it in controller through `$scope.startSpin()` and `$scope.stopSpin()`;

Please find my plunker at [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/00lrsMO8dMpBSots9zlI?p=preview). Here the spinner is not appearing at all.

The following is my code for starting and stopping spinner.

```
 $scope.startSpin();    
    DashboardsDataService.getNetSpendOverTimeData()
      .then(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
        $scope.stopSpin();  
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple you just need to remove the

```
spinner-key="spinner-1"
```

and will just work fine!

the final code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.16"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/spin.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-spinner.js"></script>
   <script src="app.js"></script>
   <script src="services.js"></script>
   <script src="controllers.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

   <span us-spinner="{radius:30, width:8, length: 16}" ></span>

       <div>
        <pre class="code">{{data | json }}</pre>
      </div>  

  </body>

</html>
```

plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/yTIsH9uvD5JZEePMyeAi?p=preview

Comment: Now what happening is after getting data from the promise the spinner starting to load and never stops!!!!. What the expected functionality is before  DashboardsDataService.getNetSpendOverTimeData(), spinner should start after the promise is successfully resolved the spinner should stop. But that is not happening with your suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug: https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner/issues/26 spinner keys won't work.

What worked for me was registering every spinner in an array: when you call .spin(spinnerName) just add {spinnerName: true} to some controller's array, when you call stop(spinnerName) change it to {spinnerName: false}. Then show/hide the spinner with ng-if based on an expression like ng-if="mySpinners['spinnerName'] == true"